# Adverb placement, in phrases, clauses?

Tags: sentence-construction, adverbs

I think these seem like phrases, may you place an adverb here? May adverbs go mostly after verbs?

> **Since** I ran, the dog followed me.
>
> I ran **since**, the dog followed me.

I think these seem like clauses, where may you get to place an adverb?

> He ran **hastily**.
>
> He **hastily** ran.

Comment: *Since* is a preposition or a conjunction, and your first two examples mean different things.  *Since* in your examples is equivalent to *because*.  

(Note that *since* can also be used to express the time a condition has been in existence - i.e. *Since 2:00 I have been hungry.* - this is not related to *because*.)

Answer (score 1):

Just like ultrasawblade said, "since" is not an adverb. In this case, it means "because". The first sentence means

> Because I ran, the dog followed me.

The second doesn't make any sense with the comma where it is. If you remove the comma, it means

> Because the dog followed me, I ran.

As for your real question about where you can place an adverb, before or after the verb is fine. You could even place it before or after the entire clause.

> Hastily, he ran from the dog. (Before the clause)
>
> He hastily ran from the dog. (In the clause, before the verb)
>
> He ran hastily from the dog. (In the clause, after the verb)
>
> He ran from the dog hastily. (After the clause)

I can't think of any examples where the meaning is different when you move the adverb.